# When comments are moved to chat, notify everyone whose comments have been moved

Tags: feature-request, comments

I don't know if this is a duplicate, but personally I feel like this one thing would be a good addition. Maybe make it switchable (so you can turn it off), but I don't think these things happen too often to be annoying. Right now when comments are moved, simply for their amount and not really that they are off-topic, that kills the conversation.

It often happens to me that someone answered me in comments, comments have been moved to chat and I don't see the response. I am not sure if it's possible to pertain all the pings when comments have been moved to chat. But it would be nice, of course, if **that** was implemented.

Comment: What are you expecting to do with this information?  As a general rule, you should not notify people of something unless there's something you expect them to do with that information.

Comment: This feels like it's a major change from the original question, and should likely be rolled back.

Comment: Couple of things 1. You keep changing the goal-posts on us by repeatedly editing your question to ask for different features. 2. Your question body doesn't actually say what you're asking for, it only explains (in a single sentence) what your problem statement is. The first is problematic because you already have an answer and editing your question significantly can invalidate the answers. This is strongly discouraged. The second is problematic because one of the most important things about a feature request is to say what you're asking for and thoroughly explain how it solves your problem.

Comment: If you want to ask for a different feature, ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What conversation? First of all, that's [not what comments are for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Second, if somebody replies to your comment in chat, you'll get a [notification anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/295232), just like when somebody mentions you in a comment. If the 'conversation' carries on in the comments without you being mentioned, you don't get a notification in the current situation. Why do you need to know if the comment thread has been moved to chat if there's nothing new for you?

Comment: See the edit, please.

Comment: If the comments are moved to Chat before he saw them the original notification would be removed (I think) since the comments are no longer extant. (If he is the post owner he would get a new notification because of the comment saying "comments are not for extended discussion...", but if he is not the post owner then he will have no notifications.)

Comment: _"that's not what comments are for"_ On the other hand, it **is** what chat is for.