# Do question authors receive a second notification if I undelete my previously deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, notifications, global-inbox, undelete

When posting an answer, the question author's receives a notification. Let's assume I delete my own answer, edit it and then undelete it. Will the question author receive a second notification?

Comment: Nope, only post creation causes a notification.

Comment: No; I've added this case to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/295232).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Only the creation of the answer notifies the question author. However, you can leave a comment on their question letting them know that you updated your answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, the OP won't be notified about of any changes of existing answers.

You can notify them yourself with a comment at the question though.