# How can I get notified when a flag I raised on a comment has been reviewed?

Tags: support, notifications, comment-flags

How can I get notified when a flag I raised on a comment has been reviewed? (I don't want to manually check `https://*.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/*`)

Comment: You can't. There is no notification for handled flags.

Comment: @rene Thanks for the information. You're welcome to convert it into an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319353/what-events-trigger-an-inbox-notification)

Comment: @Jenayah those answers don't mention flags being handled as something that either does or does not lead to inbox notifications as far as I can see.

Comment: @RobertLongson yeah, that's the idea. If something isn't on this FAQ list, then it doesn't trigger an inbox notification. Hence, no, a comment flag review does not trigger a notification, which answers this question.

Comment: @Jenayah well there's another answer on that FAQ that's supposed to cover things that don't lead to a notification and flags are not listed there either so I really don't think that question's answers cover this.

Comment: @RobertLongson That other answer only lists "notable" events that don't trigger a notification. It still means that anything not in the first answer's list doesn't trigger a notification.

Comment: Notifications don't have to necessarily go through the notification inbox.

Answer (score 4):

Flags of any kind are meant to be fire and forget for the most part. You can only find what happened to them if you directly look at your flag history.

Generally comment flags when marked as helpful will result only in the deletion of the offending comment. For the most part if a comment has been removed then we should all just move on.

If you think that more needs to be done e.g. there's a stream of rude or abusive comments from the same user then raising a custom mod flag on the post (rather than on any particular comment) and explaining the issue that way is likely to get better results.