# Multipart answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, multiple-answers

For each question, one has the option to submit more than one answer.

Each answer has a character limit.

It's possible that to properly answer a question, one needs to go over that character limit.

Is one allowed to post a "part 1" answer, then when running out of space, submit a second "part 2" of the same answer, as a continuation, etc.?

Technically if the second answer contains more relevant information than the first, it could be a "separate" answer; and the fact that it also can be easily read as a continuation of the first is incidental.

Or maybe not?

Comment: Something worth thinking about is many sites don't show answers in chronological order, and you can pick the sort. So answer 2 won't always follow answer 1

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I hear you. But one can still hypothetically say at the beginning of the second answer that it's a continuation of the first, and provide a link, and similarly at the end of the first

Comment: There are some posts where something like 'linking answers together' happened like [Build a working game of Tetris in Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life) on [codegolf.se], and some of the [tag:faq] posts here on Meta.SE, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/): It's usually done by putting some kind of list of links in either the question or accepted answer (if that one is still pinned to the top on those sites, which is site-specific), that gives you the 'order' to read things in.

Comment: Whether it is allowed (or welcomed)... that's something for individual communities to decide upon, and can very well be different for different posts on the same site.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted so harshly? It's a perfectly legitimate question, especially from a newbie. Even if the answer is No, the question might be useful to others.

Comment: It's being downvoted because it's a bad idea. This is how Meta SE typically works.

Comment: @SurpriseDog The lack of research and disagreement together will just about guarantee a negative score.

Comment: *one needs to go over that character limit* ... really? Are you saying 30,000 characters is not enough to address a question? What was the question? The meaning of life? If you need to write a book to answer a question, maybe there is something wrong with the question?

Comment: I actually did something like that with [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) on [networkengineering.se]. Having such a complete answer covers many questions we get there that can be closed as duplicates because it is a subject that comes up over and over as people move into the field. Each of the two parts has a link to the other part because they end up being non-consecutive.

Comment: @ron nice. Looking at those answers I see that they don't have negative votes, which is proof that it's relevant to do. Did you get special permission to make it or just did it and it worked out?

Comment: I just did it because questions keep coming up, and the original answers, while very good, did not completely answer some of the questions, so it made it hard to close some as duplicates. That was originally something I created for something else, and I adapted it for the site. The constant IP addressing and subnetting questions get quite tiresome, and it is a basic skill that constantly gets asked about. Having a comprehensive answer that covers everything is quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example on Stack Overflow where I needed to post two answers to get around the character count limit: [Counting inversions in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47845960/4014959). That highly popular question was nine years old when I posted my answer, with a lot of existing answers demonstrating numerous algorithms, in various languages. My answer adds several more algorithms (in Python) and compares the performance of all the Python solutions.

I didn't have enough space to include the test results in my main answer, so I posted the results in a separate answer, with links connecting the two posts. I made the "results" answer Community Wiki so I don't earn any rep for it.

My answer was well-received, and it has scored rather well, even though it's a late answer "competing" with dozens of older answers.

Answer (score 11):

> Is one allowed to post a "part 1" answer, then when running out of space, submit a second "part 2" of the same answer, as a continuation etc.?

No. There's no way to link answers together such that they're considered a unit.

If a question is so broad that a proper answer would require going over the character limit then it should be closed as "Needs more focus".

> "Also it's not asking about linking two answers, only if one is allowed to continue the answer in another answer..."

When I say "link together" I mean there's no way for the system to treat them as one answer. Different sort orders can separate the answer parts from each other so that visitors might not even realize the answer is continued someplace else.

More importantly, people may down vote both parts anyway since neither post fully answers the question.

Comment: Hi. The answer is question is here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/131740/31763 which is focused on one topic, but by it's nature continues to grow as more relevant conversations take place. Also it's not asking about linking two answers, only if one is allowed to continue the answer in another answer etc

Comment: @YakkOv Without fully reading this, it seems to be an interview. Those are inherently not answers. You could summarise it, and that could be an answer, while the full interview is hosted elsewhere and linked to as supporting material.

Comment: Providing a transcript of an interview is not answering the question. Summarise the source and explain the main points, then link to the full version, don't quote it all entirely word-for-word.

Comment: @nij where should it link too? Does SE provide a free hosting website with unlimited bandwidth and uptime with no ads?

Comment: Seriously, does Stack Exchange have to provide the internet connection, device, comfortable seat for you to write answers from as well? It is not the job of other people to do what you are responsible for, and your inability or unwillingness to find a correct place does not justify using the wrong place instead.

Comment: @nij they don't have to provide any comfortable seats, because they don't demand that people sit in comfortable seats. If the official rules of SE say that one can only post an answer that is linked to an external source, then they should provide a way to do that, unless they want their users spammed with 3rd party ads that may be necessary to pay for the hosting for such a site?

Comment: You don't appear to be interested in understanding what was said, only in justifying what you want to do, so, go ahead! Post everything everywhere!

Comment: @nij okay, if you insist

Comment: *"Also it's not asking about linking two answers, only if one is allowed to continue the answer in another answer..."* @YakkOv But you would like for both answers to be considered a unit, right? Otherwise, the correct thing to do would be to down vote both answers since neither of them provide a complete answer to the question. That's what I mean by linking the answers together. T

Comment: What's legally considered a unit? Is the entire stack exchange one unit?

Comment: If you don't actually care whether people see the rest of your answer, why bother writing it?

Comment: Hi . The question asks about someone who wants to write a complete answer which doesn't need any elaboration. To do that sometimes someone needs to go over the limit . I don't know where it's only implied that I "don't want" anyone to see the continuation, and I'm not sure how that answers the question of what is legally considered a unit.

Comment: When someone comes across one post in your multiple-post answer, do you expect them to vote on its quality based on just the one post as if it's meant to be a complete answer, or do you expect them to find and read all of your posts and vote based on that? I don't know how to be clearer than this. Do you expect multiple answer posts to be seen and treated as one thing or not?

Comment: No they can each be voted on separately for what they contribute
The question is only if one is ALLOWED to continue the same answer to multiple parts

Answer (score 7):

Well - *where* applicable, and quite a few sites discourage this, the point of multiple answers is for separate *distinct* answers.

To borrow from the help pages

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Your answer ought to be the *minimum self contained answer that answers the question* and in most cases that's enough.

Looking at the example you gave in the comments to another question - it's not a summary or precis of what the question needs, it's a large quote (and nothing else!). It's a bit unusual in that it's a primary source - but it's worth considering how much of it *exactly* you need for the post, and the bulk of it might be better in a blog post or elsewhere.  You *ought* to be referencing *just* the critical bits and linking back.

Comment: All of the points the other person mentioned in the interview are very relevant for the question, as he discusses specific sources, and without the context of the entire interview much of it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 7):

Apart from linking separately posted answers as a single one, another reason I think it might be frowned upon is that **there is a character limit for a reason**. If the limit happens to prove an obstacle, the question is either way too broad, or you should really trim down your answer.

But, as mentioned in comments and answers alike, different communities may have different rules and traditions. **My suggestion is to ask on the appropriate Meta site.**

Comment: Some answers legitimately require more space. If one asked what is every word in the dictionary, one needs a lot of characters to refer to them all

Comment: @YakkOv If one were to ask that, that question would be closed for being too broad. Or for being able to be answered by a dictionary (which is a rule on the site that question would be asked).

Comment: regardless, before it's closed, the answer is still valid. One time a question asked on stack overflow was how to validate all mimeTypes on a request, and the only valid, complete answer is to list all of the mime types in a JSON. Any other answer which involves libraries etc are outsourced, and those links might be taken down