# How can I view the list of my suspensions on a given SE site?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I know that past suspensions aren't public information (aside from using e.g. archive.org), but I wonder how I can view the list of my own suspensions on a given SE site. Assume that I can't use my email history, because emails can be thrown away.

Answer (score 14):

Emails can be thrown away, but the corresponding inbox notifications won't be. You should be able to scrape [your global inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox), looking for message type "moderator message", because that's similar to what I did when trying to determine [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/295232). The script I used for that is [here](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/59b3fd67d37e81994547506f7eed18d9); it could be modified to look for moderator messages only and output links to them. Not all moderator messages carry a suspension, but I guess it's a decent start.