# Notification when your edit has been rolled back

Tags: feature-request, notifications, rollbacks

It would be helpful if I could get a little SE inbox notification when one of my edits has been rolled back. I know there are no consequences for a rollback, but I would like a notification so I could see why my edit was incorrect. This would give me a better understanding for the future. Is it possible to create this feature?

---

**Edits and updates:**

- To my knowledge, this is not a feature yet so I am adding the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag.
- A helpful comment pointed out that "Wikipedia does notify editors if one of their edits is reverted".
- Kodos Johnson's answer mentions the follow feature, but my response would be: does it really make sense to follow every post you edit? It would be more helpful to just automatically get an update when a rollback on your edit happens.

Comment: Not that I get a lot of rolled back edits, but for the 1 or 2 times that someone has rolled back my edits (that I am aware of).

Comment: Does anyone know if following a post causes a notification if a post is rolled back? If it does, perhaps that could be the answer. If not, I think that the logic should be updated so that a rollback on a followed posts causes a notification to be sent.

Comment: @KodosJohnson You don’t get a notification when edits on your *own* posts get rolled back. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317898/323179 (I asked that before you could follow a post like that, so I guess it would make sense to ask about followers getting a notification too in that post.)

Comment: I might add that Wikipedia does notify editors if one of their edits is reverted.

Answer (score 6):

I absolutely support this.  If a user makes a few edits and a good chunk of them get rolled back, they should be notified why so they don’t continue filling the queues with bad edits.

A quote from you:

> My response would be: does it really make sense to follow every post you edit?

No, it does not.  I much prefer the idea of getting an update like with normal edits.

And in vein of notes for reopens/closures/edits on deleted posts,  I would advocate being notified of a rollback on a deleted post for us 10K users.

Comment: This assumes good faith on the editors part. If that is not the case this could start a rollback war.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be a good use of the [Follow feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network). If you click the “Follow” link under a post, you get notifications for all sorts of interactions on the post. In my opinion this would be a good solution since you are actively opting in to receiving notifications.

However, a user mentioned in a comment that the Follow feature does not seem to send [notifications for rollbacks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317898/not-notified-about-rollback). Hopefully that gets fixed.

Comment: If someone is making a substantial number of edits and a lot of them are being rolled back, they should be actively informed of that, because clearly they're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Nij I thought about a bit and removed the part about users who make a substantial number of edits. But for now, I think the Follow feature would be a good option for those users who would like to keep tabs on their edited posts (whether this feature is implemented or not).

Comment: Yes, follow is good for people who *actively want to* know. But there are many people who *probably should* know, and many people who *don't know that they can* know.

Comment: I edit a lot of posts. I don't want to follow them, because then I'll get notified about *everything* that happens on that post, and I don't really care about 99% of the conversation that occurs under the post (there's often a lot, depending on the post).  But I *do* want to know if someone thought my edit was bad enough to roll back, so that I can address that.

Comment: @Nij "If someone is making a substantial number of edits and a lot are rolled back" > I think in such a case, notifying the person that makes the edits isn't as useful as perhaps an automatic moderator flag may be. After all, if there really is a problematic behavior here, having the user dismiss a notification and continue the behavior isn't going to solve it! If you're asking this because you've noticed such behavior, perhaps raising a moderator flag on one of the edited/rolled-back posts can work in the mean time :)

Comment: Are we not going to assume good faith then? A reasonable person is going to see a bunch of edits reverted, and think *heck, why is that? am I doing something wrong? better check the guidelines again*. If it continues after notification and continued revertion, sure, ping a mod for someone being a fool/tool/troll. Or why not both, and tell the user they're being reverted often, maybe do something about it, along with mod flags to say hey, someone to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the good reasons mentioned in the other answers, I would support this as useful in getting notified in potential *"edit wars"* with the OP.
Unless I am looking back frequently at a post I edited (e.g. corrected tagging), I cannot know, if my edits were rolled back (unjustified) by the OP or other users.

At least, if I notice such situation when I edited twice (rolled back the roll back), I usually flag for moderator attention.